# How to set 'index' for Bokeh TimeSeries

Tags: bokeh, timeserieschart

Bokeh Newbie here finding that some of the learning examples are not working for me. In particular, I'm trying to use `TimeSeries` as in [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/charts.html#timeseries) and set an `index` like so:

```
t = TimeSeries(dt[dt['type'] == 0][['value', 'date']], index = 'date')
show(t)
```

This is generating the following lengthy error message (which disappers when I remove `index = 'data'` above)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-af5f4a3c6c5e> in <module>()
      2 print(dt[1:10])
      3 dt.set_index('date')
----> 4 t = TimeSeries(dt[dt['type'] == 0][['value', 'date']], index = 'date')
      5 show(t)

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builders/timeseries_builder.py in TimeSeries(data, x, y, builder_type, **kws)
    100     kws['x'] = x
    101     kws['y'] = y
--> 102     return create_and_build(builder_type, data, **kws)

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.py in create_and_build(builder_class, *data, **kws)
     64     # create a chart to return, since there isn't one already
     65     chart_kws = { k:v for k,v in kws.items() if k not in builder_props}
---> 66     chart = Chart(**chart_kws)
     67     chart.add_builder(builder)
     68     chart.start_plot()

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/charts/chart.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    112         # supported types
    113         tools = kwargs.pop('tools', None)
--> 114         super(Chart, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    115 
    116         defaults.apply(self)

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/models/plots.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     76             raise ValueError("Conflicting properties set on plot: background_fill, background_fill_color.")
     77 
---> 78         super(Plot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     79 
     80     def select(self, *args, **kwargs):

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/model.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     81         self._id = kwargs.pop("id", make_id())
     82         self._document = None
---> 83         super(Model, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     84         default_theme.apply_to_model(self)
     85 

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/core/properties.py in __init__(self, **properties)
    699 
    700         for name, value in properties.items():
--> 701             setattr(self, name, value)
    702 
    703     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/core/properties.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
    720 
    721             raise AttributeError("unexpected attribute '%s' to %s, %s attributes are %s" %
--> 722                 (name, self.__class__.__name__, text, nice_join(matches)))
    723 
    724     def set_from_json(self, name, json, models=None):

AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'index' to Chart, possible attributes are above, background_fill_alpha, background_fill_color, below, border_fill_alpha, border_fill_color, disabled, extra_x_ranges, extra_y_ranges, h_symmetry, hidpi, left, legend, lod_factor, lod_interval, lod_threshold, lod_timeout, logo, min_border, min_border_bottom, min_border_left, min_border_right, min_border_top, name, outline_line_alpha, outline_line_cap, outline_line_color, outline_line_dash, outline_line_dash_offset, outline_line_join, outline_line_width, plot_height, plot_width, renderers, responsive, right, tags, title, title_standoff, title_text_align, title_text_alpha, title_text_baseline, title_text_color, title_text_font, title_text_font_size, title_text_font_style, tool_events, toolbar_location, tools, v_symmetry, webgl, x_mapper_type, x_range, xgrid, xlabel, xscale, y_mapper_type, y_range, ygrid, ylabel or yscale
```

**What is wrong here and how can I fix it?** For reference, here's some rows of `dt` printed out:

```
   value  type                      date  index
1   0.55     1 2016-04-12 06:00:00+00:00      1
2   0.55     1 2016-04-12 11:30:00+00:00      2
3   0.55     1 2016-04-12 06:30:00+00:00      3
4   0.55     1 2016-04-12 12:00:00+00:00      4
5   0.55     1 2016-04-12 12:30:00+00:00      5
6   0.55     1 2016-04-12 08:00:00+00:00      6
7   0.55     1 2016-04-12 08:30:00+00:00      7
8   0.55     1 2016-04-13 07:30:00+00:00      8
9   0.55     1 2016-04-12 13:00:00+00:00      9
```